# Disable Python Error Underlining in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I don't know why but while using VS Code I can't seem to disable pylint or any linting for python.

[image: example]:

I dont want any of the underlining

I don't like having it show errors in the text editor, only after running the code. I installed the Python extension for VS Code and included all of the settings to disable python linting in the *settings.json* file:

```
"python.linting.enabled": false,
"python.linting.lintOnSave": false,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
"python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false
```

However, I still want to be able to turn it on and off so I don't just want to change the colour to transparent (also since the errors still show up in the scroll bar).

I want to be able to toggle the setting, 'Python > Linting: Enabled' but nothing happens when I toggle it, the linting is always there

Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: It is not linting it are **Errors**, hover over the squiggles and read the tooltips

Comment: You shouldn't disable this feature, imo. It's pointing out errors e.g. the missing colon at the end of `def func(x)`. Fix the errors rather than disable the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It was prompted by 'Microsoft Language Server' not the linters such as pylint. You can change the language server to remove these prompts:

In settings.json change from:

```
"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
```

to

```
"python.languageServer": "Jedi",
```

Not only the linters but also the language server can linting your code. Such as Pyright extension starts the Pyright language server can also do this.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I don't really understand why you're trying to disable something that helps a lot especially in python which is a interpreted language unlike javascript. But the main reason which comes to my mind about this error is because you're just disabling and sharing the `settings.json` of the user that is like a global configuration for all projects opened with `VSCode`, but you have another `settings.json` file inside the directory of the file(code shared) named as `workspace` configuracion that has `pylint` activated and it always overrides the user configuration as [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) official documentation points. So you should check both of them and if you have to disable `pylint` workspace configuration. Hope this can help you to understand what's going on.

Comment: I disable the python linting global because it complains a lot about stuff that does not matter

Comment: It's because you've never personalized `pylint`